# Как отследить клик на блок и на все его дочерние элементы JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Столкнулся с проблемой.

Сделал событие клика на весь документ $(document).click... Которое закрывает модальное окно по клику вне площади окна, но когда я кликаю на дочерние элементы всё равно происходит закрытие.

Например смоделируем ситуацию:

```
<form class="modal_form-container">
    <input/>
    <button>принять</button>
</form>



$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.modal_form-contaner')) {
        closeModal();
    }
});
```

По клику на input и на button всё равно модальное окно закрывается, как это исправить?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest  Если у элемента есть ближайший родительский элемент с классом "modal_form-container", то не закрывать. У jquery тоже есть такой метод

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так!
Добавляем нужным элементам атрибут для опознавания(я захотел data-hide, можете придумать свой)

```
<form class="modal_form-container">
    <input data-hide />
    <button data-hide>принять</button>
</form>
```

Ну и в функции реализовал проверку(Есть ли данный атрибут у элемента, на который ткнули мышкой)

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!e.target.hasAttribute('data-hide')) {
        closeModal();
    }
});
```

Comment: Очень плохое решение, особенно если элементов будет много..

Comment: Так в e передается только один элемент... Какая разница в данном случае, сколько элементов на экране. Однако, зачем инчально повесили события клика на весь document вопрос к автору вопроса

Comment: Я про атрибут..